# Can I alias a member of a base class in a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have the following classes:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
  protected:
    T theT;
    // ...
};

class Derived : protected Base <int>, protected Base <float> {
  protected:
    // ...
    using theInt = Base<int>::theT;     // How do I accomplish this??
    using theFloat = Base<float>::theT; // How do I accomplish this??
};
```

In my derived class, I would like to refer to `Base::theT` using a more intuitive name that makes more sense in the Derived class. I am using GCC 4.7, which has pretty good coverage of C++ 11 features. Is there a way of using a `using` statement to accomplish this kind of how I tried in my example above? I know that in C++11, the `using` keyword can be used to alias types as well as eg. bring protected base class members into the public scope. Is there any similar mechanism for aliasing a member?

Comment: I think you either need references or probably rather a function which won't take up space in the derived class. :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xeo's tip worked. If you are using C++ 11, you can declare the aliases like so:

```
int   &theInt   = Base<int>::theT;
float &theFloat = Base<float>::theT;
```

If you don't have C++11, I think you can also initialize them in the constructor:

```
int   &theInt;
float &theFloat;
// ...
Derived() : theInt(Base<int>::theT), theFloat(Base<float>::theT) {
  theInt = // some default
  theFloat = // some default
}
```

EDIT:
The slight annoyance is that you can't initialize the the value of those aliased members until the main body of the constructor (ie, inside the curly braces).

Comment: Note that this increases the size of the derived class by `sizeof(void*)` times the number of references. That's why I included the suggestion of a simple getter function that is named `theXXX`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right. Luckily, I don't think an extra 8 bytes will kill me since I don't have a lot instances of the Derived class, so I can stick with the easier-to-type reference version when I access the data member.