# c++11 aliasing base template class variable doesn't work in template derived class, when base class has two or more template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, alias

I started off with a wish that I wanted to create a more readable name for a base class variable in derived class. So I could have nice understandable semantics for users of the derived class. Fortunately, there was an easy solution to make a reference in the derived class to base class member variable (this helped to find it: [Can I alias a member of a base class in a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784734/can-i-alias-a-member-of-a-base-class-in-a-derived-class)). So I got the following to as a solution which works fine and I was happy for some time (code example is a bit arbitrary, but it was best I came up with):

```
template<typename T>
class Color {
public:
    T color;
    // other stuff
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Rectangle {
public:
    T1 sideA;
    T2 sideB;
    // other stuff
};
class Square: public Rectangle<float, float>, public Color<float> {
public:
    float &borderColor = Color<float>::color;
    float &side = Rectangle<float, float>::sideA;
    // other stuff
};
```

Then I wanted to make Square class more generic to enable users to use it whatever type they want. After making it more generic I ended up with following template class Square:

```
template<typename T>
class Color {
public:
    T color;
    // other stuff
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Rectangle {
public:
    T1 sideA;
    T2 sideB;
    // other stuff
};
template <typename T>
class Square: public Rectangle<T, T>, public Color<T> {
public:
    T &borderColor = Color<T>::color;
    T &side = Rectangle<T, T>::sideA;
    // other stuff
};
```

And I ended up with compilation errors (line num are correct):

```
../src/test.cpp:18:28: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     T &side = Rectangle<T, T>::sideA;
                            ^
../src/test.cpp:18:28: error: declaration of ‘T Square<T>::T’
../src/test.cpp:14:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
 template <typename T>
           ^
../src/test.cpp:18:29: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
     T &side = Rectangle<T, T>::sideA;
                             ^
../src/test.cpp:18:25: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     T &side = Rectangle<T, T>::sideA;
                         ^
../src/test.cpp:8:7: error: provided for ‘template<class T1, class T2> class Rectangle’
 class Rectangle {
       ^
make: *** [src/test.o] Error 1
```

The problem is on line 18. Aliasing base template class Color (line 17) works fine (base template class with one template parameter). But for some unknown reason for me base template class with two parameters doesn't work.

I am using:
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Compiled with: g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"

This is my first post.. please edit, improve or clarify whenever necessary.
All help is very appreciated, I have been stuck here for several hours already.

Comment: Using a typedef (`using Rect = Rectangle<T, T>;`) fixes it. Compiler bug ?

Comment: Seems like a gcc bug to me, your code compiles on both clang and VS2013. The workaround is to use a `typedef` as suggested above.

Comment: Yep, typedef worked. I made a gcc [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61690) - hope it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC parses the member initializer ambiguously because of the comma, this is actually a (very old) defect in the standard, see [DR 325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325)

You can work around it using `{}` instead of `=`

```
    T& side{ Rectangle<T, T>::sideA };
```

Comment: This is the root reason for this problem. Ty for the link. @Jonathan Wakely

Answer (score 1):

While I have no idea why it does not work, did you try something like this (works for me):

```
private:
   using Rectange<T,T>::sideA;
protected:
   T &side = sideA;
```

Have you tried different compilers? As mentioned it might be a glitch with gcc..

Comment: I will use this workaround till compiler guys get this bug fixed. Thank you.